# jQuery change event with IE6

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

It is indeed quite unfortunate that my client still uses IE6.
using jQuery 1.4.2

The problem is that I open a window using a click event and do some edit operation in the new window.
I have a 'change' event attached to the row of a table which has input fields. Now when the window loads for the first time and I make a change in the input for the FIRST time, the change event does not fire. however, on a second try it starts working.
I have noticed that I e.g. I run a dummy page, i.e. create a new page (I work with Visual Studio) and run that page individually , the 'change' event works just fine.

What it going on, and what can I do, besides going back to 1.3.2 (by the way that doesn't work either, but haven't fully tested it yet)?

```
<!--HTML-->

<table id="tbReadData">
<tr class="nenDataRow" id="nenDr2">
 <td>
 <input type="text" class="nenMeterRegister"  value="1234" />
  </td>
<tr />
<table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tbReadData').find('tr').change(function() {
alert('this works');
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that HTML correct? The row is not being closed.

```
<table id="tbReadData">
<tr class="nenDataRow" id="nenDr2">
 <td>
 <input type="text" class="nenMeterRegister"  value="1234" />
  </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Also, the JavaScript is incorrect. It is missing a closure.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tbReadData').find('tr').change(function() {
            alert('this works');
        }); // added );
});
</script>
```

Comment: yes it is correct. It's just been posted in a hurry. don't worry about it though, i was using 1.4.1 and when I used the latest version of JQuery 1.4.2, and the bloody thing worked.